# Space not working in android

Tags: android

I have an android app where I accept various inputs from the user but the problem is that i am not able to use space in any of the EditText fields I dont know what the problem is and is very frustrating...Any help would be appriciated.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_frm_place"
        style="@style/Normal_CustomFontStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"

         android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
        android:hint="Enter From Place" />
```

This is my EditText xml representation

Comment: where you want to use space in this code

Comment: i must be able to enter spaces at will, anywhere i just want my space button to be enabled

Comment: please mention your style code also

Comment: possible duplicate of [android edittext inputfilter should accept space,character & number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487465/android-edittext-inputfilter-should-accept-space-character-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
```

to

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "
```

which include space

Answer (score 3):

Try this way,I hope it will helps you .

Just update your **EditText** Like this

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,"","
```

Or

```
 EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
yourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence cs, int start,
                    int end, Spanned spanned, int dStart, int dEnd) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(cs.equals("")){ // for backspace
                 return cs;
            }
            if(cs.toString().matches("[a-b-c-d-...-A-1-..0 ]+")){
                 return cs;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following codes

```
 EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
  yourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
  new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence cs, int start,
                int end, Spanned spanned, int dStart, int dEnd) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(cs.equals("")){ // for backspace
             return cs;
        }
        if(cs.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
             return cs;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to incluse " " in android:digit property because this property defines all the characters you could enter in Edittext and you didn't specify space in it. SO just add a " " after 0 and it will work